# How do you make a javascript variable more than one thing?

Tags: javascript, variables, numbers

There might have been an answer quite like the answer to this might be, but I did not know what terms to type in. 
So here is my question. I am trying to make a javascript variable that equals more than one thing. This is what I think might work, but it does not work. Here it is:

```
var chars = [1-9]
}
```

That doesn't work, so does anyone know a solution? If you can think of a way, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A variable can only have one value and any given moment. There are composite constructs within JavaScript, like an array or an object. An array may contain multiple values, however, when you assign that array to a variable, that variable has exactly one value, and that value is a reference to the array itself. I'd recommend you start with with a good introductory guide to the language. See [MDN: Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array:

```
var chars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Or an object:

```
var chars = {
    thing1: 'foo',
    thing2: 'bar'
};
```

These can be considered as multiple things, as you can do `chars.thing1` in my second example for instance, but really it's still one thing. Think of it as a group or collection of things in a thing.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider clicking on the checkmark beside it to accept it. Btw your site is very colourful… too colourful if you ask me :-P